# Seems like my Python syntax is a bit off when copying a python program

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a self-replicating Python program. Currently, the code I have looks something like this:

```py
from sys import argv
import os
script = argv
name = str(script[0])
try:
    os.mkdir('testFolder')
except:
    pass
os.system(r'copy ' + name + ' testFolder')
```

This returns the following error:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

What's the cause of this, and what would be correct syntax?

Comment: Can you share the full error traceback?

Comment: @CoryKramer He did, `The syntax of the command is incorrect.` is the full error you get when running the script

Comment: That's because it's not a Python error. It's the error raised by the `os.system` i.e. by `copy`

Comment: Switching away from `os.system()` and instead copying files with the Python `shutil` module would moot this problem.

Comment: (Using `os.system()` this way has serious security problems as well -- if you don't control `name`, someone can abuse your script to run arbitrary commands).

Comment: Instead of that `try/except` you can just use `os.makedirs('testFolder', exist_ok=True)` instead of `mkdir`

Comment: And beyond the reliability and security issues, using `os.system('copy ' + ...` makes your software specific to Windows, instead of working everywhere Python does.

Comment: @eccentricOrange I believe that is exactly the point... (*"I'm trying to create a self-replicating Python program"*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the correct arguments to copy - namely Windows paths are `\` separated - e.g. `C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\script.py` while Python's `sys.argv[0]` will give you `/` separated path - `c:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/script.py`

Comment: Indeed, `name.replace('/', '\\')` seems to make it work...